# Sequence diagram and activation rectangle

Tags: oop, uml

Making UML sequence diagram in VS 2010RC I've observed that there is no activation rectangle in first object. Is this correct? Not according to my tutor and I have to quote him:
"Finally, you have no activation rectangle for the userInterface instance, so the initial message could never have been sent."

But I'm thinking that if guys from VS did that it must/should be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activation rectangle has been erased from UML 2 specification because this is not an UML metamodel element. This was just graphical and no metamodel equivalence was possible.

I think that this UML2 sequence diagram is more a regression compare to UML 1.x. I think that it is not because activation bar have not metamodel element that it is not an important graphical information !!! 
Some tools still have activation rectangle with UML2 because they refused to take out this important UML grahical information !!
It means that VS 2010 is right and activation rectangle are not anymore included in UML2 but .......